# Vuejs computed property for loop print all values, but returns only one value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vuejs computed property 'for loop' print all values, but returns only one value.

```
computed: {
            orderedUsers: function () {
                //console.log(this.bannerData)
                //console.log(this.subBannerData[0].event_pi[0].id);
                this.secondSubBanner = [];
                for(let i=0; i<this.bannerData.length;i++){
                    this.subBanner = this.bannerData[i].pressInformation;
                    //console.log(this.subBanner.event_pi);
                    for(let j= 0;j<this.subBanner.length;j++){
                        this.secondSubBanner = this.subBanner[j].id;
                        console.log(this.secondSubBanner);// output: 257, 256, 254,261
                    }
                }
                return [this.secondSubBanner];
            },


sortedArray(){
            this.v = this.orderedUsers;
            console.log(this.v);// output:261
        }
```

Can someone tell me where is my mistake? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you returning `[this.secondSubBanner]` and not just `this.secondSubBanner`? Also you don't appear to be using `this.secondSubBanner` as the array you declare it as. I don't see how you can be outputting a list of ids when you're assigning only one id at a time.

Comment: change to `this.secondSubBanner.push(this.subBanner[j].id);` then you'll be appending to the list

Comment: @MattEllen I have used the Array brackets around `this.secondSubBanner` so that it returns the values as array and I can sortout the Json depending on this array values. Thank you for your spontaneous reply. It has helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is that you're declaring `this.secondSubBanner` as an array, but then setting its value to an id. I guess what you really want to do is the following:

```js
for(let i=0; i<this.bannerData.length;i++){
    this.subBanner = this.bannerData[i].pressInformation;
    for(let j= 0;j<this.subBanner.length;j++){
        this.secondSubBanner.push(this.subBanner[j].id);                   
    }
}
```

And then change the return to be:

```js
return this.secondSubBanner;
```

Also, if the value of `subBanner` and `secondSubBanner` are not used outside of the function then drop the `this.` and declare them with `let`, because you're creating unnecessary object state.

For example:

```
let secondSubBanner = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

`this.secondSubBanner = this.subBanner[j].id;`

You are re-assigning the value each time. So it will only return the last value in the loop.

What you should do instead is push the values like so:

`this.secondSubBanner.push(this.subBanner[j].id);`

Comment: I have tried to upVote but I have got this notification. "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Answer (score 0):

Now the `Console.log(this.v)` outputs an empty array at starting
`[ ]
 (4) [254, 256, 257, 261]`

which results in `_orderBy` property cannot sort the Json i guess.

```
 `sortedArray(){
                this.v = this.orderedUsers.sort();
                console.log(this.v);//output: 254,256,257,261
                return _.orderBy(this.bannerData, this.v)// output: 257,256,254,261
            }`
```

Although the sortedArray() prints the id's in order, I do not get the return value in order when I use `_.orderBy` property of Vuejs.

Comment: I think this is a separate question